# How to combine string[] to string with spaces in between

Tags: c#

How to parse string[] to string with spaces in between
How would you refactor this code?

```
    internal string ConvertStringArrayToString(string[] array)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(array[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(' ');
            builder.Append(array[i]);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is not Parsing but a form of Combining.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a method for that already:

```
String.Join(" ", array)
```

This will put a space between each element. Note that if any of your elements are empty strings, you'll end up with spaces adjacent to each other, so you may want to filter those ahead of time, like this:

```
String.Join(" ", array.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
```

Comment: "It seems overkill..." - that depends not on how simple this is but how often it is used. If it's a logical unit you want a single definition.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, you are right, there might be a reason to put trivial code in a method just to put a name on it.

Comment: Just a side note, if an item in the array is empty, you'll end up with two spaces.  Sometimes desirable, sometimes not. `String.Join(" ", array.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))` will remove extra spaces between your array items.

Comment: In most situations I use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace instead of IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: @user1775543: That is a good option. It was a new method in .NET 4, so it wasn't so well supported when the answer was written.

Answer (score 4):

```
internal string ConvertStringArrayToString(string[] array)
{
    return string.Join(" ", array);
}
```

Of course, it's silly to have a method that just calls another, so you could go the whole way and remove your method altogether...

Comment: I agree with your statement for this situation, but disagree with the blanket statement `it's silly to have a method that just calls another`. Method forwarding is useful when it comes to abiding by the Law of Demeter, as well as when producing wrappers around third-party APIs, as any breaking changes can be caught and handled in one place.

Comment: @Lukazoid Agree that it can be helpful when dealing with third party APIs or also when you want to add pre-conditions to the method over and above its own.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ [Aggregate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) method:

```
string result = array.Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + " " + next);
```

Comment: I'm curious how well this would perform compared to the original, as it appears to allocate a load more string objects as it processes.

Comment: Right, LINQ is not for free. I believe in this particular case String.Join would be a great solution, BTW I was not able to see String.Join implementation usign reflector, it would br pretty interesting to see how it would do join since strings are immutable, so perhaps aggregate would perform in relatively the same time/memory complexity?

Comment: The `String.Join` implementation most likely finds out the size of the final string by adding the length of the strings in the array and the separators, allocates a string buffer, copies the strings to it, and returns the string buffer as a string. The `Aggregate` solution actually performs quite bad in comparison, as it will copy the same data over and over again. With each additional array item the execution time roughly doubles, so if you have a long array it will get really slow.

Comment: String.join uses a stringbuilder under the hood. The aggregate method will also work great if you use the seen overload and initialise a stringbuilding in there.